# SQL: INNER JOIN SELECT makes the whole query return nothing

Tags: mysql, sql, join

There are 3 tables, named as `account_has_account1, account_has_photos, photos_has_message_photos` where `account_has_account1` have columns `account_id, account_id1, status, type_id` and this table takes care on storing accounts following to another account

`account_has_photos` stores information about all the photos one account has uploaded, it's columns are `photos_id, account_id, type_id`, this also stores `likes` according to `type_id`

`photos_has_message_photos` stores all messages posted to a photo, its a relational table from `photos` and `message_photos`

i need to fetch a count of all likes from `account_has_photos` where `type_id = 1` which points to `like` from table `type`

i have done this `SQL`:

```
SELECT account_has_photos.photos_id as id, "photos" as type, account_has_photos.update_at, account_has_photos.account_id, posts.total as total_messages, likes.total as total_likes
FROM account_has_account1 
    INNER JOIN account_has_photos 
        ON (account_has_photos.account_id = account_has_account1.account_id1 AND account_has_photos.type_id = 17)
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT photos_has_message_photos.photos_id, count(*) as total
        FROM photos_has_message_photos
        GROUP BY photos_has_message_photos.photos_id
    ) posts
        ON(posts.photos_id = account_has_photos.photos_id)
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT account_has_photos.photos_id, COUNT(account_has_photos.photos_id) as total
        FROM account_has_photos
        WHERE account_has_photos.type_id = 1
    ) likes
        ON (likes.photos_id = account_has_photos.photos_id)
WHERE account_has_account1.account_id = 7 AND account_has_account1.`status` = "Active"
```

the first `INNER JOIN account_has_account1` is for showing all accounts that one account is following, The second `INNER JOIN photos_has_message_photos` is only for getting the count of all posted messages from a account's photos.

At this point everything goes fine, but when i insert the third `INNER JOIN account_has_photos` again, the query result is now 0, the purpose of this third `JOIN` is for getting a count of likes a photo has which is stored in `account_has_photos` where `type_id = 1`

The rest is for setting the general conditions for the search.

Again the problem only happens in this query

```
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT account_has_photos.photos_id, COUNT(account_has_photos.photos_id) as total
        FROM account_has_photos
    ) likes
        ON (likes.photos_id = account_has_photos.photos_id)
```

it could be that no likes are found on any photo, i have made the test for searching it separately and as i said, there is no like made on any photo, i didn't add any record because i want it to say 0 on count as it is going to be shown alot

Comment: Right now your likes are simple a couple of all photo_id 's that exist in account_has_photos.  So any time an account has a photo it is liked?  Is there a column missing?

Comment: @Matt i just updated the question adding the missing condition in the join

Comment: Gordon is right about missing your group by but I would bet you can write this query using joins without the sub selects and 1 aggregation.  But I too wonder do you want all of the photos or only photos with likes? in account_has_photos is photos_id repeated (seems unlikely) because if not the count of photo_id for likes will always be 1

Comment: @Matt i want all photos found on the first `JOIN`, doesn't matter if they have likes or not, i need the count to give me 0 if there are no likes

Comment: is photos_id the unique identifier for account_has_photos or is it repeated in the table?  If repeated what is the unique_identifier?  If you count on a left join and results are not given it will give you a 0 instead of null.

Comment: @Matt There are 3 unique columns, which are `account_id, photos_id, type_id`

Comment: so account 1 photo 1 type=1 will never repeat.  That means your likes will always be 1 because you can only have 1 record per photo that is type 1.  Is there perhaps another column that contains a count of likes in account_has_photos?

Comment: @Matt no, the other columns are timestamps of the row

Comment: Understand that SQL runs right to left with inner queries. INNER JOIN returns only matching keys, so i suggest you change your structure and make sure the values you think are passing arr retained by the time the outer query is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is much different way to write your query that should yeild the same results.

```
SELECT
    account_has_photos.photos_id as id
    ,"photos" as type
    ,account_has_photos.update_at
    ,account_has_photos.account_id
    ,COUNT(photos_has_messages.photos_id) as total_messages
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT likes.photos_id) as total_likes
FROM
    account_has_account1
    INNER JOIN account_has_photos
    ON account_has_photos.account_id = account_has_account1.account_id1
    AND account_has_photos.type_id = 17
    LEFT JOIN photos_has_message_photos
    ON photos_has_message_photos.photos_id = account_has_photos.photos_id
    LEFT JOIN account_has_photos likes
    ON likes.photo_id = account_has_photos.photo_id
    AND likes.type_id = 1
    WHERE account_has_account1.account_id = 7 AND account_has_account1.`status` = "Active"
GROUP BY
    account_has_photos.photos_id
    ,"photos"
    ,account_has_photos.update_at
    ,account_has_photos.account_id
```

I would recommend changing:

```
,COUNT(photos_has_messages.photos_id) as total_messages
```

to

```
,COUNT(DISTINCT photos_has_messages.WhateverTablesUniqueIdIs) as total_messages
```

Also this line

```
,COUNT(DISTINCT likes.photos_id) as total_likes
```

will always give you 1.  so if likes does repeat photo_id then you also want to count whatever that account_has_photos unique identifier is....

Answer (score 1):

Your last subquery is missing a `GROUP BY`.  Try this:

```
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT account_has_photos.photos_id, COUNT(account_has_photos.photos_id) as total
    FROM account_has_photos
    GROUP BY account_has_photos.photos_id
) likes
    ON likes.photos_id = account_has_photos.photos_id
```

You may also want to replace the `INNER JOIN`s with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` if you want rows with no likes.

Comment: forgot to add the type condition for the join, i just updated the question, although when i use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` the row returns `NULL`